# wicked_pdf: UTF-8 encoding issue on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf, wkhtmltopdf-binary

In my Rails 5 app I use **wicked_pdf** and **wkhtmltopdf-binary** gem for generating PDF from HTML. But there is some problem while generating PDF on production. Currency symbol is not displaying properly, but it's working fine in development.

Here is my PDF image.

[my production pdf screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V52PM.png)

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
gem 'wicked_pdf', '~> 1.1'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '~> 0.12.3.1'
```

My Controller code:

```
def generate_order
  @order = @user_builder.orders.find(params[:id])
  render pdf: 'billing_pdf',
  layout: 'layouts/pdf.html.erb',
  :show_as_html => params[:debug].present?, #true
  encoding: 'utf8'
end
```

I tried lots of solutions from Stackoverflow to other similar questions. They all suggested me to add meta in layout file. I also added it in my layout file.

**edited**

my PDF layout file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Billing</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class='container'>
     <%= yield %>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I will be really grateful if someone could point out what is going wrong in this case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It can be fonts problem. I had same issues on heroku in past. Solution was to add fonts buildpack to heroku config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other that encoding issues (which look to be set up fine, only I'd use `Content-Type` to be sure) you may be having issues with fonts on production machine.

Things to try:

1. Rendering other unicode characters, if some them render correctly - it's not an encoding problem
2. Newer `wkhtmltopdf-binary` - (0.12.4 at the time), or `wkhtmltopdf_binary` (other gem, is stale at the moment)
3. Ensuring production server has `fontconfig` and `libfontconfig` installed and set up, also that it contains fonts that you're using
4. Using webfonts (in my tests a while ago eot format appeared to work, but now woff2 may be better)

Comment: Thanks! Vasfed it's Resolved after installed **fontconfig** on my server.
Thanks a lot man! i really appreciate it :)

Comment: @Riskyleopard glad that helped ) Consider marking answer as the solution and upvoting